# Overriding 2 methods with the same name in a Java class implementation in JRuby

Tags: java, polymorphism, jruby, overriding

I would like to create an implementation of Apache Jena's [OpVisitorByType](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.jena/jena-arq/3.0.0/org/apache/jena/sparql/algebra/OpVisitorByType.java#OpVisitorByType) in JRuby but I want to also override two super methods with the same method name: `visit(OpBGP op)` and `visit(OpTriple op)`.

Here is what I did:

```ruby
class Visitor < org.apache.jena.sparql.algebra.OpVisitorByType
  include_package 'org.apache.jena.sparql.algebra.op'

  java_signature 'void visitN(OpN op)'
  def visitN(op)
    puts op.inspect
    op.getElements.to_a.each {|elOp| self.visit(elOp)}
  end

  # [...] Redifining also all required abstract methods: visit2(Op2 op), visit1(Op1 op), visitFilter(OpFilter op), visitLeftJoin(OpLeftJoin op)

  java_signature 'void visit(OpBGP op)'
  def visitBGP(op)
    puts "OpBGP #{op.inspect}"
    op.getPattern.getList.as_a.each {|triple| self.visit(triple)}
  end

  java_signature 'void visit(OpTriple op)'
  def visitTriple(op)
    puts "OpTriple #{op.inspect}"
  end
end
```

With this implementation, the Ruby method `visitBGP` is never called.

If I rename it `visit` then it will be called but it will be called for all calls to `visit(<Op class> op)` and not only for `visit(OpBGP op)`.

Is there a way to define those 2 different methods that need to implement Java methods with the same name, same arity but different argument class?